# How to install Kubuntu 12.04 amd64 on an Asus N56V notebook

Tags: 12.04, installation, uefi

## SOLVED

I'm trying to install Kubuntu alogng with the preinstalled Windows 7.

I boot from CD
Create three partititons: / (ext4), swap and a 100MB reserved bios

All installs correctly, but I'm not able to boot Kubuntu

From the bios setup disappeared the option to use legacy bios instead of UEFI (or at least I cannot find it)

I have the option to create a new boot entry, but I don't know what to type in.

What can I do?

Thanks
   Mirto

=========== added 10 Lug 18:54 ========================

Seems relate to bug 972122 ( https : // bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-efi/+bug/972122 )
The message I saw when the EFI boot partition was missing is the same reported in
https : // launchpadlibrarian.net/99750202/EFI-warning.jpg

The bug is marked as fixed-released
What I'm missing?

There is any particular install CD using partman-efi?

============== added 12 Lug 18:27 =========================

I've tried boot-repair using a ubuntu-secure-remix - I updated boot-repair before using it.

I've sent the error output posted at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1088164/ to boot.repair@gmail com

Boot-repair is suggesting other actions and I'll try

============= added 12 Lug 19:23 ==========================

Second try: non luck log at http://paste.ubuntu.com/1088300/

============= added 13 Lug 18:05 ==========================

At power-on magically the ubuntu boot entry appeared

Boot-repair was the solution

Comment: If this question is solved, do an upvote to the answerer and accept that answer. If you solved the question, then write an answer yourself and accept that. This is the equivalent of putting [SOLVED] word at the title. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disk is GPT-type, so you need either an **EFI** or a **BIOS-boot** partition.
Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), update it, and click `Recommended Repair`.
Note the URL that will appear. Reboot and check if your problem is solved. Indicate the URL if not.

[image]