# Keyboard backlight not working on an Asus N56V

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, asus, backlight

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166263/fn-keys-not-working-on-an-asus-n56v).

The FN keys are not working

Using answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166261/keyboard-backlight-not-working-on-an-asus-n56v) I installed the asus-wmi-dkms_0.2_all.deb.gz package

Now, using xev I see that the keys emit keycodes (for backlight keys xev says for fn-f3 and fn-f4 keycode 237)

But no keyboard backlight, also volume keys have no effect

================ original question ========================================

I cannot enable the keyboard backlight
Seems that the leds class is missing
I've not found the classes used in [Keyboard light hotkey (Fn + F3 and F4) rarely work on an Asus G60J](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134021/keyboard-light-hotkey-fn-f3-and-f4-rarely-work-on-an-asus-g60j/157986#157986)

Description of my framework:

===========================================================

Machine: Asus N56V laptop

===========================================================

Software

- Kubuntu 12.04 amd64
- kernel (3.5.0.5-generic) and drivers from xorg-edgers fresh X crack ppa

===========================================================

Hardware and problems

- after installation do not boot - SOLVED using boot-repair
- every couple of hours the system freezes - SOLVED using 3.5 kernel
- keybord FN keys - NOT WORKING
- Keyboard backlight - NOT WORKING
- Nvidia GEFORCE GT - NOT USED glxgears says 60 fps
- Ethernet Atheros card - SOLVED install alx driver
- external subwoofer - SOLVED adding options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

==========================================================

Solutions

see the answers to the [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162047/how-to-install-kubuntu-12-04-amd64-on-an-asus-n56v-notebook) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166261/keyboard-backlight-not-working-on-an-asus-n56v) question.

==========================================================

Comment: Please do not make multiple similar questions. Please use one question if they are related(as some of your questions are).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For N56V and N76V, you need :

- a 3.5 kernel (from quantal)
- to get the subwoofer

  - I add on /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf this line: options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4
  - reboot and select 2.1 output in audio pref
- to get the fn keys + keyboard backlight

  - install asus-wmi-dkms_0.2_all.deb.gz package (from http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12057336&postcount=49)
  - reboot
- to get the GeForce (when you want)

  - install bumblebee and driver from x-swat repository
- to get the Ethernet

  - build/install alx module (http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/alx)

Comment: Tried fn-keys  all installed but no backlight  now xev says for fn-f3 and fn-f4 keycode 237  In /sys didn't appeare any vew class as  Seems that kekeys are sending codes but nothing is attached to these events also audio volume fn-f11 fn-f12 do not work  Wha can I try?  Thanks

Comment: I added "options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4" and rebooted. 4.0 option showed up instead of 2.1 in sound pref. When I select 4.0 subwoofer works as "rear right" and rear left is empty. Normal speakers work normal (front left - front right). How can I add 2.1 option to sound preferences?

Answer (score 5):

Only thing that works for me is echoing like this:

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness
```

[Keyboard light hotkey (Fn + F3 and F4) rarely work on an Asus G60J](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134021/keyboard-light-hotkey-fn-f3-and-f4-rarely-work-on-an-asus-g60j/157986#157986)

Answer (score 1):

I bought an Asus N56VM laptop recently and sent the company an email concerning the following problem: **Do not know how to turn on the keyboard backlight.**

The following answer (edited) from Asus solved my problem:

1. Go to Control Panel to uninstall the ATK package.
2. Download and reinstall the ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities. Here's the [link](http://support.asus.com.cn/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=390&m=N56VM&os=30&ft=14&f_name=ATKPackage_Win7_64_Z100020.zip#ATKPackage_Win7_64_Z100020.zip).
3. Download and reinstall the KB Filter Driver. Here's the [link](http://support.asus.com.cn/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=390&m=N56VM&os=30&ft=14&f_name=KB_Filter_Win7_64_Z1003.zip#KB_Filter_Win7_64_Z1003.zip).
4. Use <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to adjust the backlight of the keyboard for a try.

Comment: Is this answer really about Ubuntu? Seems like Windows-specific to me.