# How do I configure an Asus N56VM?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, asus

I'm trying to configure all the hardware and make sure that everything is working on an Asus N56VM-S4060x. I've made some progress based on other answers, but there are still a number of things that aren't working.

From a fresh install I have done the following,

- Installed kernel 3.5 (following [these instructions](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-kernel-3-5-rc-ubuntu-12-04-precise-using-ppa), based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/166330)
- Installed asus-wmi (not sure if this is necessary though)
- Installed asus-wmi V999.01
- Installed bumblebee
- Tried to compile the alx module for Ethernet (failed)

After I installed kernel 3.5 the touchpad right click worked. After installing the asus-wmi the fn keys worked, except for the brightness functions.

After I installed bumblebee the launcher no longer displays the icons, but still works if you click in the right place. The other change I saw was the the task switcher (alt-tab) was different, but does not display the expected image.

I tried to compile the alx driver but after following the instructions had this error,

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-9-generic/build M=/home/duncan/src/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-9-generic'
scripts/Makefile.build:44: /home/duncan/src/compat-wireless-2012-07-03 p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `/home/duncan/src/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [/home/duncan/src/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx] Error 2
make[2]: *** [/home/duncan/src/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/duncan/src/compat-wireless-2012-07-03-p] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-9-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Some other things which are not quite right:

- Right click area of the mouse pad can result in a left-click
- Screen does not automatically dim when removing the power cord

So the questions:

- How do I get the GeForce GT 630M to work correctly? (and how do I know if it is being used instead of the Intel graphics?)
- How do I get the brightness keys to work?
- Do I need a particular version of the alx module?
- What else might I need that I am missing?
- Does the asus-wmi provide all of the necessary power management features?
- Is there a way to stop certain areas of the touchpad from being a left click? i.e. I want to prevent left-clicks when I am trying to right click
- What do I need to install for more advanced power management?

Answer (score 2):

About your first question:

Bumblebee switches to use the Geforce card only if you manually tell it to do so. Start programs that you want to run with the Geforce card with: `optirun program`

You can test it with `glxspheres` vs. `optirun glxspheres`.
See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/124685/how-to-make-nvidias-optimus-work-on-linux/).

It worked for me with Asus N76VM and Ubuntu 12.10. There also seems to be a user interface currently being developed for bumblebee that lets you configure which programs automatically start with the graphics card.