# No sound from external subwoofer "Sonic Master" on an Asus N76VM

Tags: 12.04, sound, asus

A few weeks ago I bought an Asus n76vm notebook looking forward to it's 'superior sound'. This sound system compromises an external subwoofer which amplifies bass and is connected to a special output jack. Ubuntu 12.04, however, does not detect this subwoofer. How could this be solved?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Multimedia_Entertainment/N76VM/#specifications

Comment: Try this : [http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/asus_n76vm#son](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/asus_n76vm#son) It's in french but it's working for me.

Comment: This may be an anwser: http://askubuntu.com/questions/166261/keyboard-backlight-not-working-on-an-asus-n56v.

Comment: worked for me! https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_N55SF thanks for all the help given me!

Answer (score 6):

to get the subwoofer
I added on the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4
```

then rebooted and selected 2.1 output in audio pref. It should work right away :) got this information from [Keyboard backlight not working on an Asus N56V](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166261/keyboard-backlight-not-working-on-an-asus-n56v)

hope it helped!

Comment: I did what you said and rebooted. But there is 4.0 option instead of 2.1 when I select 4.0 subwoofer works as "rear right" and rear left is empty. How can I add 2.1 to sound preferences?

Answer (score 3):

Which sound card are you using?

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
```

If so, I think you have a common problem with many new laptops: you are lacking the 2.1 surround mode enabled in your audio driver. Here a solution that worked for me: [intel audio fix](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_N55SF)

Here are three things to do:

1. `echo 'options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4' | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`
2. `sudo -H gedit /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf`

   ```
   [Mapping analog-surround-21]
   device-strings = surround40:%f 
   channel-map = front-left,front-right,lfe,lfe 
   paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker
   priority = 7
   direction = out
   ```

   **Note**: On Asus N76VB running on the newer kernel `3.8.0-30`, change the last line to be this instead:

   ```
   direction = output
   ```
3. `sudo -H gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

   ```
   enable-lfe-remixing = yes
   ```
4. Reboot.

You should now be able to see your "analog surround 2.1" among your possible Hardware settings in the sound menu.

"Analog Surround 4.0" is also working but changes the loudness from Front to Rear.

Additionally you can install the GNOME alsa mixer to boot your basses.

Comment: can this fix proposal be made more generic? so that more people con fix their subwoofer behaviours?

Comment: This works for me, but now ALL of my sound is output through the mini-subwoofer and none comes through my standard speakers at all.

Comment: Working, but if i activate them, my mic stops working.

Comment: `analog-output analog-output-speaker` should not be on spearate line. This way only "Dummy output" is available. If there is `paths-output = analog-output analog-output-speaker`, the outputs are visible.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore   :(