# Asus Sonic Master on Asus N53SV

Tags: pulseaudio, asus, soundcard

I have read that there's a problem to get the subwoofer working in these laptops. I tried this solution [No sound from external subwoofer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189304/no-sound-from-external-subwoofer-sonic-master-on-an-asus-n76vm)
but I don't how to prove that the subwoofer is properly functioning. I use Pulseaudio equalizer and the bass sound seems to work fine, but when I go to the Sound Settings, I can't move the bar where it says 'Subwoofer' in my sound card option, so I don't know if everything is alright.
If someone has a solution I would like to know, because there isn't much information regarding this. By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits.

Thanks beforehand,
Dave

EDIT ----------- Possible Solution

Well, I will post a solution that worked for me and I think it will help a lot of users. I finally got the subwoofer working. 
Besides adding in `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` the line

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4
```

I deleted the lines with `load-module module-combine`  and `module-combine-sink` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`  (in the home folder there's also a ~/.pulse/default.pa file, I don't know if it has the lines too). Or just delete the ~/.pulse/default.pa file

To assure all the channels are working, I think this command tells me that

```
speaker-test -c6 -l1 -twav
```

I use pulseaudio-equalizer and the bass sounds very well when properly adjusted. Also, all the channels seems to work fine and the sound is even better than in Windows (where I don't have an equalizer).

I pointed out before a module-combine and module-combine-sink problem, because one day I turned on my laptop and pulseaudio didn't work. So I deleted the lines with that names (don't know if they came by default, maybe I added them sometime when I was trying to fix my speakers).

One important thing is to add, when using the equalizer, in  `~/.pulse/default.pa`  the command

```
load-module module-combine channels=6 channel_map=front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

After all this, I can now move the Subwoofer bar  in the Sound configuration. Anyways, the Equalizer does a great job and it improves the sound a lot.