# Why have I lost the 2.1 sound settings on my Asus N76VZ DH71?

Tags: 12.04, sound, pulseaudio, asus

I've just got the Asus N76VZ DH71 with a Sonicmaster subwoofer. I got the output on the sonicmaster, but essential its a right channel, not the sub.

I was following:

- [No sound from external subwoofer "Sonic Master" on an Asus N76VM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189304/no-sound-from-external-subwoofer-sonic-master-on-an-asus-n76vm) and
- [ASUS_N55SF on wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ASUS_N55SF)

to try to fix the Intel Audio bug, but after reboot, Ubuntu does not see any audio device at all.

I had to remove the new 2.1 mapping in `extra-hdmi.conf` in order to have it work again. 
The Intel Card here is

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it helped me to have some level of controle on the sub but its still in the right chanell

All needed is to pass a parameter to snd-hda-intel module. Open the file /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf (you need to create this file if there is no file with that name) and add this line at the ending of the file:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4
```

there is the url where i found it
http://th0th.me/log/enabling-subwoofer-of-asus-notebook-on-gnulinux/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [AU asks contributors](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) to “Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.”