# Asus Zenbook ux51vz 2.1 audio mode

Tags: 13.04, sound, kde, phonon

I recently purchased an Asus Zenbook UX51VZ and installed Kubuntu 13.04 x64 (all defaults still) on it and most things seem to work fine, with just a few exceptions.

adding `options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as suggested in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189304/no-sound-from-external-subwoofer-sonic-master-on-an-asus-n76vm) has enabled additional audio options, but a 2.1 profile is not among them. The external subwoofer appears to be on the back right channel in a 4.0 surround sound setup - how do I create a 2.1 profile that correctly maps that channel to the subwoofer?

Comment: I also tried the `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/extra-hdmi.conf` tweak listed in the 2nd answer to no avail. I'm assuming there's some difference between 12.04/13.04 or N76VM/ux51vz that prevents the config from working properly, but I don't know anything about alsa to know what.

Comment: Close-voters: EoL questions are only ever off topic *for that reason* if the release being used was EoL *at the time the question was asked*.

Comment: @DavidPerry Are you still looking for an answer to this?

Comment: @Seth Sadly, I long ago gave up on this one.

Comment: @Seth Please, provide your answer proposal here shortly as comment. - - I hate to see this kind of threads left open here in Askubuntu.

Comment: @Masi If someone else is experiencing this problem they need to ask a new question.