# Subwoofer not working on my laptop

Tags: sound

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Toshiba Qosmio F55 Q502 laptop, but Ubuntu does not recognize the subwoofer. This laptop has a 2.1 speaker system. Can you help me get it to work?

I tried [these instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189304/no-sound-from-external-subwoofer-sonic-master-on-an-asus-n76vm) to activate the subwoofer from the terminal and edited some files, but that didn't work out because the instructions were for an Asus laptop.

Can someone give me some instructions how to enable the subwoofer on my laptop?

```
aleksandar@QOSMIO:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset PCI Express Graphics Port (rev 07)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 03)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 03)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 03)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 (rev 03)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 (rev 03)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev 93)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation ICH9M LPC Interface Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9M/ICH9M-E) 4 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G94 [GeForce 9700M GTS] (rev a1)
08:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 02)
20:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller
20:00.1 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller
20:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller
20:00.3 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. MS Host Controller
20:00.4 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. xD Host Controller

aleksandar@QOSMIO:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b008 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1546:01a5 U-Blox AG 
Bus 006 Device 004: ID 04f3:0234 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Subwoofer is built in laptop. You can see from [picture](http://i.i.cbsi.com/cnwk.1d/sc/929d9e07-4b27-4b24-96b2-97722779fec7.jpg), right above of the HDD cover.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please add what version of Ubuntu you are using. Also state what you have tried until now to resolve the problem. [Edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/406258/edit) to add the information.

Comment: Thanks for fast respond. I just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I trayed to install driver from realtek for linux based systems, i mean, hd audio drivers, beacuse my audio chip is realtek. And i also went in sound settings, and saw that i can only rise volume on speackers but now subwoofer. I also found some instructions, but those were for asus laptop, one of the users made question. I folowed all instructions but it didin't work, i guess its because this is a toshiba laptop.

Comment: You should *really* put the information in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: Could you please give us the link the instructions you tried. Also post the output of lspci and lsusb. Please add the information to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, google couldn't clarfiy this. Is the subwoofer build-in or is it externally connected to the laptop?

Comment: It is internal/built in subwoofer. There is link of picture in description.

Comment: Does someone knows the solution? I edited daemon.conf file, I add real life mixing "yes" value and number of speakers to 3 (it was 2 before). I saved the file and when I restarted my laptop , ubunutu didn't want to boot. It git stuck. So I installed new, again.